# What's the minimum time counted for billing in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Ec2 instance hour calculated by hour by hour. If you just start and close an instance, it still counted as one hour.

How Heroku handle this? By Minute or By Hour?

**Lets assume my app usage exceeds 750 Free Dyno Hour Limit**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heroku prorata to the second. A dyno costs $0.05 per hour. So if you go over 750 hours you will be charged at $0.05 per hour or $0.000833333 per minute. In fact, pretty much all addons also follow the same billing model too.

You can read about billing and charges as https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing#cost

Comment: Thanks. I've gone through the whole docs. But I was not able to find they prorata to the second.

Comment: the first line of Cost. "Dynos cost $0.05 per hour, prorated to the second. For example, an app with four dynos is charged $0.20 per hour for each hour that the four dynos are running. However, see the 750 free dyno-hours per app."

Comment: oh! I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I will say, though, that the previous answer seems to be more accurate for the web dyno versus a worker dyno.  Heroku's automated sleep cycle for your web dyno tries to prevent it from running too long when it's idle, say, for more than an hour.  For the free web dyno it must sleep at least six hours per day for it not to incur charges.  As long as you set the scaling to 1 for your web dyno and it sleeps then it should be free.

That said, when you add your first worker dyno those same automations aren't applied to this dyno.  It presumably won't be triggered to sleep on idling for an hour.  This means that unless you manage it you'll likely be charged $34.50 for each worker dyno per month.  I wouldn't exactly call this lying to the customer but most people start off with that first free dyno, get comfortable with that and then innocently think that the next dyno will behave in a similar way--it won't and you'll likely get tagged paying more money than you'd bargained for.  That's $414-per-year for a dyno.  Compare this with Amazon's t2.micro cost of $150-per-year for one instance or $75-per-year for a 50% duty cycle of same.

As they say, "the devil is in the details".  Heroku might be cheap for vanity websites but it's a bit costly if you have a database and worker thread (without any scaling otherwise whatsoever).